# SS2.0 Retrieve Image object from html Canvas and save to File Cabinet

Tags: html5-canvas, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am experimenting with some script at present to take an image from the file cabinet, push the url to an HTML Canvas, retrieve the width/height (to insert into custom fields and re-size the original image.

Above is OK within a client script - no problem.

However, what I want to know is

1. How can I grab the resized image as a File object (N/file) and save it to the file cabinet without user interaction.
2. Is there a way to work with a HTML canvas from a server-side context.

For #1, it seems difficult, as the N/file module is not available to ClientScript, so may need to push to a SuiteLet?

Some of my code so far

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();

img.onload = function () {

// set size proportional to image
canvas.height = canvas.width * (img.height / img.width);

// step 1 - resize to 50%
var oc = document.createElement('canvas'),
octx = oc.getContext('2d');

oc.width = img.width * 0.5;
oc.height = img.height * 0.5;
octx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, oc.width, oc.height);

// step 2
octx.drawImage(oc, 0, 0, oc.width * 0.5, oc.height * 0.5);

// step 3, resize to final size
ctx.drawImage(oc, 0, 0, oc.width * 0.5, oc.height * 0.5, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

var imageContent = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
var decodedContent = btoa(imageContent);

scriptContext.currentRecord.setValue({fieldId:'custitem_image1_width', value: img.width})
scriptContext.currentRecord.setValue({fieldId:'custitem_image1_height', value: img.height})


img.src = scriptContext.currentRecord.getValue({fieldId:'custitem_image1_thumb_url'})
```

Above is running currently in CSS pageInit, and I have a separate UES beforeLoad script creating an INLINEHTML field `custpage_htmlcanvas`.

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this? I current have a base64 string and running into unexpected errors when trying to create the file in NS

Comment: I ended up using an external image processing API...    https://kraken.io/?ref=e7ac2be6a3ad   it's quite good.

Answer (score 1):

```
var fileObj = file.create({
name: 'test.txt',
fileType: file.Type.PLAINTEXT,
contents: 'Hello World\nHello World',
description: 'This is a plain text file.',
encoding: file.Encoding.UTF8,
folder: 30,
isOnline: true
});
```

Use file module in suitescript 2.o then create a file in filecabinet.

Comment: I tried this, but either got Unexpected error, or after decoding base64, got a blank file. Not quite sure how to get the raw "contents" from the canvas.img into the file.